# Oracle apex charts mobile

Tags: oracle, charts, oracle-apex

how can I scroll page on my dashboard when I press on my chart on mobile. It activates tooltips and chart info on finger press but I want to scroll up or down on page. I tried every option without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find soluiton, set template to carousel container and show next and prev to hide. Simple way to do it without additional coding